# MySql table with potentially *very* many columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

A friend who is a recruiter for software engineers wants me to create an app for him.

He wants to be able to search candidates' CVs based on skills.

As you can imagine, there are potentially hundreds, possibly thousands of skills.

What's the best way to represent the candidate in a table? I am thinking `skill_1`, `skill_2`, `skill_n`, etc, but somewhere out there there is a candidate with more than `n` skills.

Also, it is possible that more skills will be added to the database in future.

So, what's the best way to represent a candidate's skills?

---

[Update] for @zohar, here's a rough first pass at teh schema. Any comments?

[image]

Comment: A table mapping skills to candidates would be the relational way.

Comment: !! I didn;t think of that !! Feel free to post an answer. Thanks & upvote

Comment: There's no candidate to skills relationship in this schema.

Comment: The skills are associated with a job. The candidate uses different skills on different jobs, and a complete list of all skills can be obtained by searching all jobs associated with the candidate. That *seems* ok to me, but I certainly welcome improvements (+1)

Comment: Follow the `[EAV]` tag.  And good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need three tables (at least):

One table for **candidates**, that will contain all the details such as name, contact information, the cv (or a link to it) and all other relevant details.

One table for **skills** - that will contain the skill name, and perhaps a short description (if that's relevant)

and one table to connect candidates to skills - **candidatesToSkills** - that will have a 1 to many relationship with both tables - and a primary key that is the combination of the candidate id and the skill id.
This is the relational way of creating a many to many relationship.
As a bonus, you can also add a column for skill level - beginner, intermediate, skilled, expert etc'.

You might also want to add a table for job openings and another table to connect that to the skills table, so that you can easily find the most suitable candidate for the job based on the required skills. (but please note that skills is not the only match needed - other points to match are geographic location, salary expectations, etc'.)

Comment: Since I also want job history, I added a `jobs` table. Also one for the `companies` - I added an image of the schema to the question. There are probably lots of fields missing yet, but I think it's the foreign keys that are important at this point, to show show table linkage.

Comment: Upvoted but I would prefer singular form for table names. i.e. `Job` instead of `Jobs`

Comment: I am having trouble accessing the schema, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941064/somewhat-complex-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment98538046_55941064). Can you help?

Comment: I think Gordon's answer is probably the best I've seen to that question.