# Somewhat complex MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema diagram below. Basically, at the bottom are skills, then jobs, then candidates (ignore the companies for now). Each skill can be associated with multiple jobs, and a job can have multiple skills. Each job applies to a single candidate who can have (had) multiple (historical) jobs, each with a single company.

I just can't figure out the queries to find all candidates with skill X.

In fact, it gets complicated, because X isn't just a single skill, it can be multiple skills, with Boolean operators, such as

> find all candidates with (skill="C++" and skill="UML") and NOT(skill="Python")

where the `(skill="C++" and skill="UM"L) and NOT(skill="Python")` part is a string which ought to contain a valid ,SQl sub-query, but I can't figure the rest of the query.

---

[Update] when I said "such as", I did not mean exactly that query string. I am trying to find a way handle any query string of skills. Eg `skill=VB` or `skill=VB and skill=C` or `skillFreeRTOS and not skill=Windows`

Btw, the schema came form the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560171/mysql-table-with-potentially-very-many-columns) It looks good to me, but ...

[image]

Comment: But according to the diagram candidates doesn’t have skills, it’s the job that has skills.

Comment: Some sample data might help...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's precisely my difficulty. I ***think*** that I want to find every job which matches the skills clause, then for each job get the candidate and return that. But, I don't know how :-(

Comment: If each skill can be associated with multiple jobs , and a job can have multiple skills then there is a many-to-many relationship between skills and jobs. But I don't see the linking table that would establish that relationship.

Comment: Each skill has a `job_id`  in the `skills` table - you an link "up" from skill to job, but not "down" fro a job to its skills(is my schema wrong?) Please see th answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560171/mysql-table-with-potentially-very-many-columns) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find all candidates with (skill="C++" and skill="UML") and NOT(skill="Python")

I would recommend `group by` and `having`.

```
select j.candidate_id
from jobs j join
     skills s
     on j.job_id = s.job_id join
     skill_names sn
     on sn.skill_id = s.skill_id
group by j.candidate_id
having sum(s.skill_name = 'C++') > 0 and
       sum(s.skill_name = 'UML') > 0 and
       sum(s.skill_name = 'Python') = 0;
```

The caveat is that this gets the skills attached to *jobs*, not directly to the candidate.  Perhaps that it is a requirement for your definition of skill, but it is possible that you simply have no jobs for some skills for some candidates.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unless I change the schema - which looks good to me(?) - then it has to be that way. Find the skills, then the jobs where those skills were used and finally the candidates who worked those jobs. Btw, will you query cover searching for multiple skills, which were used at multiple jobs.? E.g search for `C++ AND Pyton` where candidate X has those skills, but has CC++ from job Y and Python from job Z?

Comment: The user will enter a query. *Example* `(C+ +AND UML OR Python), which I can programmatically graft on to your `HAVING` clause. So, that should be just find; this will generically handle any valid user entered search term. It's  just, as I asked, whether your query above would work across all job/skills for the candidate.

Comment: @Mawg . . . You can adjust the `having` conditions to handle the jobs as well as the skills.  However, that would be a *different* question, and you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I will take this as a start point, and teach myself from there. If still stuck, I will ask a better question, but this answer has certainly been good guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (not tested in editor)

```
select distinct c.candidate_id
from candidates c
where 
  exists (
    select 1
    from skill_names sn
      join skills s
        on sn.skill_id=s.skill_id
      join jobs j
        on s.job_id=j.job_id
       and j.candidate_id=c.candidate_id
    where sn.skill_name='C++'
    ) and 
  exists (
    select 1
    from skill_names sn
      join skills s
        on sn.skill_id=s.skill_id
      join jobs j
        on s.job_id=j.job_id
       and j.candidate_id=c.candidate_id
    where sn.skill_name='UML'
    ) and 
  not exists (
    select 1
    from skill_names sn
      join skills s
        on sn.skill_id=s.skill_id
      join jobs j
        on s.job_id=j.job_id
       and j.candidate_id=c.candidate_id
    where sn.skill_name='Phyton'
    )
```

The problem here is the skills are not related to the candidate, but the job. So the candidate could have joined the job, but it does not reveal his real skills. For a more straightforward and comprehensible model to execute that query, the skills should be directly connected with the candidate.

Comment: The problem with tying skills to candidates, not jobs, is that I could then not (easily() search for someone with skill X at company Y, or skill X within the last Z years. I think that the schema is correct (? YMMV ) . Effectively it is a tree, just like your CV/resume – each candidate has multiple jobs, each of which used multiple skills. Skills may be repeated across jobs. Each job has exactly one company (and start/end dates).

Comment: Ok I understand. I just wanted to highlight that your query WON’T return the candidates with those skills, but the candidates joined to one job which requires those skills (so, the candidate could have other skills that we never know using this model)

Answer (score 0):

could be using a subquery for skill_name IN IN ('C++', 'UML') join to skill_name NOT IN ('Python')

```
select c.* 
from camdidates c 
inner join jobs j on c.candate_id = j.candidate_id 
inner join (
select  sn.skill_id, sn.job_id
from  skill_name sn
inner join  skill s1 on s1.skill_id = sn.skill_id 
    and s.skill_name IN ('C++', 'UML')
inner join  skill s2 on s2.skill_id = sn.skill_id 
    and s2.skill_name NOT IN ('Python')
) t on t.job_id = j.job_id
```

but if you want 'C++' AND  'UML' then could be using 3 join with skill

```
select c.* 
from camdidates c 
inner join jobs j on c.candate_id = j.candidate_id 
inner join (
select  sn.skill_id, sn.job_id
from  skill_name sn
inner join  skill s1 on s1.skill_id = sn.skill_id 
    and s1.skill_name = 'C++'
inner join  skill s3 on s1.skill_id = sn.skill_id 
    and s3.skill_name = 'UML'     
inner join  skill s2 on s2.skill_id = sn.skill_id 
    and s2.skill_name <> 'Python'
) t on t.job_id = j.job_id
```

Comment: C++ AND UML, not or.  Yours only returns if either or both.  I would just add one more inner join to keep C++ and UML individually required joins

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made the question clear enough (now updated). I don't seek a solution for that specific "`(skill="C++" and skill="UML") and NOT(skill="Python")`", but for any boolean expression containing a strong of skills